# Does moment.js comparing dates not work properly?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am building a datatable and wish to compare a date string that is passed in, to todays date, and then do something based on the outcome (before today, same as today etc etc)

```
"createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
    var formattedDate = moment().format("DD-MMM-YYYY");
    var dateIncoming = moment(data.NextDue, 'DD-MMM-YYYY').format("DD-MMM-YYYY");
    if (dateIncoming < formattedDate) {
        dateDue = true;
    }
    if (dateDue === true && data.AssignedToName !== "With Caller") {
        $(row).css({ "color": "red" });
    }
}
```

So it is mainly working, but I have one record where the `dateDue` is `15-03-2017` and the `formattedDate` is also `15-03-2017`, but the css on my row is still activating.

I would normally expect this to happen if a `datetime` was also involved, and I also have several other values where `dateDue` is `15-03-2017` and these filter correctly.

Comment: You're comparing `String`s, not `Date`s. You shouldn't need to format anything for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) and [`isAfter`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/) to compare moment objects istead of `<`.

Moreover you need to remove `format()` since it trasforms moment object in string, so, as stated in the comments, in your code you are comparing strings intead of moment/dates.

Your code will be:

```
"createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
    var formattedDate = moment();
    var dateIncoming = moment(data.NextDue, 'DD-MMM-YYYY');
    if (dateIncoming.isBefore(formattedDate)) {
       dateDue = true;
    }
    if (dateDue === true && data.AssignedToName !== "With Caller") {
       $(row).css({ "color": "red" });
    }
}
```